# Re-rendering a Component Within another Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

So I have a component called `TicketView` that is used within another component of mine, which is just called `Table`. TicketView is initialized in the table just like this:

`<TableRow key={index}>
    ...
    <TableRowColumn style={{width: '80px'}}><TicketView id={row.TicketID} /></TableRowColumn>
</TableRow>`

The `TableRow` data is propogated using `Axios`, and I have a 5 second refresh on the table to use a `GET` method to refresh the table data every 5 seconds. However, during the refresh, all the inputted data is changed, but the data I need for the `TicketView` component does not change. I'm unsure how to exactly refresh the `TicketView` component from the `Table` refresh. What is the best way to undergo this?

Comment: Is the TicketView downloading it's own data then?

Comment: Yes, TicketView is downloading its own data.

Comment: That's the the problem. It should be getting it's data from a parent container then.

Comment: Hmmm, can I send it via props? there's a significant amount of data I need to pass to the component itself. I'm currently not using Redux, this is my first React project. The id value does change when the table data changes however, but TicketView does not re-render.

Answer (score 1):

So the best way according to me is pass the new data that arrives from your GET method as props to TicketView component and react will render the new values.